# Assign Some Text to particular line in UITextView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I create an instance of UITextView programmatically. I want to assign some text to particular line in UITextView programmatically. Here is my code to create UITextView.

```
UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,282,210);
[textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

For example I want to add some text to particular line (at the end of line 5).

Programmatically, how is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,282,210);  
textView.text = @"xxxxxx";
```

...

Comment: Dear Michael i want to assign some text to particular line .Not to Whole TextView.For Example Line 10 In UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit lines directly in the text view because the number of lines depends on the content size and the size of the font.

Check this question as a reference:
[How to Read Number of lines in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585470/how-to-read-number-of-lines-in-uitextview)

You could do some calculation to determine where to insert the text, but I'm nor sure if that's the best way to go around. There is probably a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Dear Locke actually i want when i stop my writing in UITextView using Keyboard.Then in next line i want  to add some text programmtically at the end of line in UITextView.,it can be on the button event.so on.can it possible plz guide me.

Comment: In that case, it's possible to append the string you want to the text entered, check the answer below on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
NSString *str=yourTextview.text;
[str stringByAppendingString:yourNewString];
```

Then add it to textview

```
yourTextView.text=str;
```

check it and let me know if any clarification you need