# Check if text in UITextView went to new line due to word wrap

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, word-wrap

How can I check if the text in a `UITextView` went to the next line due to word wrap?

I currently have code to check if the user enters a new line (from the keyboard).

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {
        ...
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the contentSize.height property of UITextView to determine how 'tall' your textview is. You can then divide by the lineHeight to figure out the number of lines. @nacho4d provided this nifty line of code that does just that:

```
int numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
```

Refer to this question for more info:
[How to read number of lines in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585470/how-to-read-number-of-lines-in-uitextview)

EDIT:
So you could do something like this inside -textViewDidChange: in order to check for a line change.

```
int numLines = textView.contentSize.height / textView.font.lineHeight; 
if (numLines != numLinesInTextView){
    numLinesInTextView = numLines;//numLinesInTextView is an instance variable
    //then do whatever you need to do on line change
}
```

Comment: That only works if the text will be there in the beginning. In my case, the text will not be there in the beginning, the user will enter text.

Comment: You can use the delegate method -textViewDidChange: This gets called after the user makes changes to the text (after the delegate method you are using returns).

Comment: But the textView's height wouldn't change?

Comment: textView.frame.size.height doesn't change, but textView.contentSize.height does change as the user types text. If you put the line of code in my answer inside the -textViewDidChange delegate method and use NSLog(@"numLines is %d", numLines); You will see the number of lines change as you type in text.

Comment: What would the if statement be?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but you could make an instance variable named numLinesInTextView. Then do something like this (untested): `int numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;` `if (numLines != numLinesInTextView){``numLinesInTextView = numLines;``//do whatever you need to do on line change}`

Comment: Sorry, that's really unreadable, I'm gonna edit my answer to include this code snippet.